# How to return the data based on days interval using mongoose match aggregate

Tags: mongoose

so, i am trying to match based 10 days interval and group then based on those dates.

so i having tried going through the docs looked up references and finally i am here with my question.

```
    var today = new Date(cars[0].date),
        oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        tenDays = new Date(today.valueOf() - 10 * oneDay);
    Car.aggregate()
        .match({ date: { $gte: new Date(oneDay), $lte: new Date(tenDays) } })
        .then(resp => res.json(resp))
        .catch(err => console.log("err=>", err));
```

so i was expecting it to return the data based on the interval mentioned on the code but i am getting empty array.

Comment: in which format date is saved in your database ? timestamp or Date ?

Comment: its saved on date based.